# Is it possible to use credentials from WebAPI Windows authentication for CSOM calls?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, asp.net-web-api2, impersonation

I have a web application, and I am looking to make use of SharePoint endpoints using the user's Windows credentials.  SharePoint 2013 does not have CORS support, so there is no way for me to send XHR requests to SharePoint from my web page, which is hosted separately from SharePoint.

My thought is then to create a separate WebAPI based web service that uses Windows Authentication.  Taking those credentials, I can then make use of the CSOM and pass those credentials through to pull back data from SharePoint with the permissions of the impersonated user.

Is this possible?  I have tried several variations, but I have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: Actually, it does seem to work now, but only if I am coming from Internet Explorer.  If I come from Chrome, I don't get prompted for credentials, and when the call passes to the CSOM part, I am getting a 401 back from that side.

Comment: Nevermind.  I was mistaken.  This only works when running from a browser on the server box.  If I run from a browser on another box, either through IE or Chrome, I get the 401 from the CSOM call.  Which means the credentials are not getting delegated in general.

Comment: Did you find a way to do. I am working on an equivalent and cannot figure this to work

Comment: @Guigui I did not find a workaround to this yet. But a possible solution that I have not investigated yet might be fronting the SP api with Tyk or Apigee.